# how do I switch on the water supply to my dishwasher?

Tags: water

I don't know how to turn on the water supply to our dishwasher. There is a blue tap on the pipe which I am not able to move. I am afraid to break something if I use too much force

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a ball valve. When closed they are perpendicular to the flow of water. When open they are parallel to it. So either left or right which probably doesn't help much unless you see some sort of stops on the side. Main reason I'm adding a comment is are you sure that's a water pipe? Not sure about plumbing in the UK but I'm in the US and that looks more like a gas pipe and valve to me.

Comment: Hi, I am in UK. I know it is a water pipe because we have somebody removing the old dishwasher. There is a stop on the left hand side which makes it impossible to move the blue handle in any directions. I thought the screw was going to do the trick but after removing it I still couldn't turn the handle left or right

Answer (score 6):

That is a standard type of valve used in the UK for connecting a water supply to appliances like dishwashers. It is sometimes called an ["appliance valve"](http://taps2traps.com/collections/isolation-valves/products/washing-machine-or-appliance-straight-valve-heavy-pattern).

[image]

Usually the appliance is supplied with a cold-fill water hose that looks like this

[image]

Though they vary and sometimes the other end of the hose is permanently attached inside the appliance.

The blue lever will turn through 90 degrees in one direction only. In your case it isn't clear from the picture whether there is enough room - the wooden partition or the flexible hose "nut" may interfere.

You can actually open the valve by forcing the lever the wrong way. It will break part of the lever but this isn't catastrophic - the valve will still work.

In the worst case you can undo the screw and remove the blue plastic lever. This will expose a  square metal end that you can turn using an appropriate tool (ideally the right sized spanner or socket but mole-grips will work).

If you remove the plastic lever it should be obvious which way it should turn - there will be a protusion in the metal casting that blocks the movement of the plastic lever in one direction.

Comment: Thanks for the input. With a bit of force I managed to move the lever